# Nested Array/Object access via [String][String]

Tags: arrays, string, haxe, openfl

In AS3 I could access a nested array/object as follows:

```
var platformObj:Object = {"filters": {"manufacturer": ["Adobe Windows"]};
trace(platformObj["filters"]["manufacturer"]); //trace output: "Adobe Windows";
```

Errors in Haxe with: String should be Int (for the second argument):
    platformObj["filters"]**["manufacturer"]**

How can I do this in Haxe/OpenFL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openfl.utils.Object` is basically just a `typedef` for [`Dynamic`](http://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html), so the following works fine:

```
trace(platformObj.filters.manufacturer); // [trace] Main.hx:6: [Adobe Windows]
```

If you *need* to use a `String` to access the fields, you can do the following using a [type check](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-type-check.html):

```
trace((platformObj["filters"] : Object)["manufacturer"]);
```

Under the hood, all of this is just [reflection](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html):

```
trace(Reflect.field(Reflect.field(platformObj, "filters"), "manufacturer"));
```

Comment: The third option was exactly what I was looking for, and makes the most sense to me, actually I was on the verge of working that out - Glad I asked anyway, it's nice to know the other ways to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You could just use dot-notation:

```
var platformObj = {filters: {manufacturer: ["Adobe Windows"]}};
// the type of platformObj is `{filters:{manufacturer:Array<String>}}` in this case
trace(platformObj.filters.manufacturer);
```

Or you can use [StringMap](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html):

```
var platformObj = ["filters" => ["manufacturer" => ["Adobe Windows"]]];
// the type of platformObj is `Map<String, Map<String, Array<String>>>` in this case
trace(platformObj["filters"]["manufacturer"]);
```

Haxe doesn't have `Object`, but has [Dynamic](https://haxe.org/manual/types-dynamic.html). You can retrieve its fields using [Reflect](https://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html):

```
var platformObj:Dynamic = {filters: {manufacturer: ["Adobe Windows"]}};
var filters = Reflect.field(platformObj, "filters");
var manufacturer = Reflect.field(filters , "manufacturer");
trace(manufacturer);
```

When you are using Haxe 3.3+ you can use `Any` instead of `Dynamic`.

The first two are safer to use. The last one using dynamic/reflection can have side effects.

Comment: What is the difference between using an Object to contain the information I mentioned vs. Dynamic? What limitations of Object would be lifted if I used Dynamic? Thanks for the StringMap mention, something I'll use in the future to be *strict*.

Comment: Haxe itself doesn't have Object, but has Dynamic.

Comment: Oh yeah, oops, I'm working with OpenFL as well, so I'm using a mix of both Haxe and OpenFL.

Comment: Ah I don't know openFL that much. Seems they created a abstract class `Object` which is an alias for Dynamic, with some extra functions. http://api.openfl.org/openfl/utils/Object.html

Comment: What are the use case differences between Any and Dynamic?

Comment: Any is a type that is compatible with any other in both ways.

This means that a value of any type can be assigned to Any, and vice-versa, a value of Any type can be assigned to any other type.

It's a more type-safe alternative to Dynamic, because it doesn't support field access or operators and it's bound to monomorphs. So, to work with the actual value, it needs to be explicitly promoted to another type.  http://api.haxe.org/v/dev/Any.html